# How does the driver in macosx get the physical address of MMIO registers?

Tags: operating-system, driver, virtual-memory, memory-mapping

The question is conceptual/theoretical, nothing about anything I am working practically on.

I understand in the virtual memory layout you have the heap, stack, data, memory mapped, etc sections

I was wondering how would it work if for example on macosx the driver wants to access one of the registers in the memory mapped IO(MMIO) region ?

I would assume that it would need to some how know the physical page number to where the MMIO region is present, but how would it get this? Any function call ?

Also, what if after a while the page was swapped out and in to a different page number ? Would it need to check/fetch the page number to the MMIO registers every time ?

Comment: I/O devices are typically not swapped - they have to be accessible from interrupt-handlers.

Comment: @MartinJames So i am a bit confused here, if I have 10 processes running, each has there own heap, data, etc and MMIO segments, right ? Now if Process 1 is launched, which all of the memory segments are bought into the physical memory ?

Answer (score 1):

How MMIO pages are discovered depends on the kind of device and platform we're talking about. On something as sophisticated and complex as a Mac, schemes like ACPI are used for assigning and enumerating MMIO addresses. Some addresses are most likely also hardcoded in Firmware and accessible to the OS via the Firmware's API. On simple embedded platforms, you'll often just find MMIO ranges hard-coded to some specific physical address.

PCI devices advertise their MMIO ranges in the [configuration space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_configuration_space), and system software (Firmware and/or OS) can decide where in physical address space the device's MMIO ranges should be located.

If the (x86/-64) CPU is running in paged/long mode, which for a Mac is true even in (EFI) firmware, the MMIO pages need to be mapped into virtual memory address space using the page table, in order to be software-accessible.

> Also, what if after a while the page was swapped out and in to a
>   different page number ?

A MMIO-backed virtual page will not be swapped out - the only reason a virtual page would be swapped out would be because the system is low on unused physical system memory, and the OS needs to reclaim some. Removing an MMIO-backed page from the page table doesn't free any system memory.